# How to handle Compressed Request in WCF service

Tags: wcf

We have a WCF REST service hosted on IIS 7 with .NET Framework 4.5. The client is sending data in GZip compressed format with request headers:

Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type: application/xml

But we are getting bad request from the server, if the request is in compressed format. We enabled Request compression by implementation of IHttpModule that will filter/modify incoming requests. From my understanding, this is failing because WCF uses original content length (that of compressed data) instead of Decompressed data. So here are my questions:

Is there any way we can fix this content length issues in IIS7/.NET 4.5? My HTTP module implementation is given below:

httpApplication.Request.Filter = New GZipStream(httpApplication.Request.Filter, CompressionMode.Decompress)`

If fixing the content length issue is not possible at server side, is there any way I can send original content length from client with a compressed request? Client side implementation is as follows:

```
using (Stream requeststream = serviceRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
   if (useCompression)
   {
       using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(requeststream, CompressionMode.Compress))
       {
           zipStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
           zipStream.Close();
           requeststream.Close();
       }

       serviceRequest.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
   }
   else
   {
       requeststream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
       requeststream.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm encountering the same thing. You could add a filter to the request using a module, but once it goes to the WCF, it still gets an exception because of now the request has a different content length.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get gzip working in WCF using wsHTTPBinding and this as the base of the web request:

```
private HttpWebRequest GetWebRequest()
{
  dynamic objHTTPReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateDefault(_URI);
  objHTTPReq.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"";
  objHTTPReq.Method = "POST";
  objHTTPReq.Accept = "gzip, deflate";
  objHTTPReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3;OfficeLivePatch.0.0; Zune 3.0; MS-RTC LM 8)";
  objHTTPReq.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://xxx.yyyy.zzzz");
  return objHTTPReq;
}
```

So give that a try. Good luck.

Comment: I tried this as well but the incoming request is still compressed so unless I add a filter, I get the compressed stream. Is there a setting to instruct WCF to recognise compressed requests?